# Application error when trying to depoy my Node,socket,twilio server to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to deploying my backend which is a node js express socket io twilio server but I keep getting the below errors.

I've tried everythign and i don't know wtf im doing wrong.

The error basically starts error:password is requird from baseTwilio.js

[

```
mongo_URL="mongodb+srv://yama08:yama08@cluster0.163andw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
JWT_SECRET="yamsmma123"
accountSid="AC15229a43940c205bea97430f26629533"
authToken="5d8d63360e64cc1fe63a13343ad6288a"

twilioconfig.js:

require("dotenv").config();
// twilioConfig.js

const twilio = require("twilio");

const accountSid = process.env.accountSid;
const authToken = process.env.authToken;

const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

module.exports = client;
```